# Select a row in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

my mapping is as follows,

```
mapping = {
        "mappings":{
          "document": {
            "properties": {
               "title": {"type": "text"},
               "users": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "user_id": {"type": "integer"},
                    "name": {"type": "text"},
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i can add data fine but when i search using

```
res = es.search(index="test", body={"query": {
    "nested": {
        "path": "users", "query": {
            "match": {'users.user_id': 1}
        }
    }
}
}
```

it returns the whole document not the specific row.

More info:

i am feeding a table to elastic search:

> user_id  |  name
>
> 1.............Joe
>
> 2 ............Mary

if i give 1 as user_id in search,  i need elastic search to return just {user_id:1, name:Joe}

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the [Nested Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-nested-query.html) where they use *bool > must* when filtering by nested objects on the document.
Also, use *term* instead of *match* when you need to filter. Match is for full text search

Try it like this

```
res = es.search(index="test", body={"query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "users", 
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {                           
                            term": {
                                'users.user_id': 1
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! but if i change user_id  to name and 1 to 'Joe' it does not return any thing , can you say why?

Comment: @RobSmith, is the name stored exactly as 'Joe'? You could try with match instead of term and see if the full text search finds the value

Comment: by default ES stores things in lowercase.  try searching for 'joe'

Comment: @jhilden _that's not quite accurate (but I understand what you mean)_ - For clarity, for a POCO string property mapped `text` data type where no analyzer is specified, and the index does not have a default analyzer specified, the standard analyzer will be used, which includes a lowercase token filter as part of the analysis chain: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html